# local DNS caching?

Tags: domain-name-system

I got a PC that I'm not using and it has some power..
I wanna have my own DNS server like a ISP has.. 
How can I go about this?
I know linux so that's no biggy.. Thought this would be something fun to do :D

Answer (score 3):

This is a little confusing since you describe another setup than you mention in the topic.

#### First Local DNS Caching

This is pretty easy to achieve using `dnsmasq`

To set this up install the `dnsmasq` package of your distribution. Since Debian based systems are common these days I'll assume this distro.

```
$ apt-get install dnsmasq
```

Now edit `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` and set the `listen-address` directive to the IP address of the network interface connected to your network.

Now restart the dnsmasq service

```
$ /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
```

Edit your `resolv.conf` and enter the nameservers supplied by your providers or another one:

```
# Google DNS 1 
nameserver 8.8.8.8
# Google DNS 2
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Now you can set your Linux machine as DNS server of your LAN clients and use DNS caching.

To test if it is working you might use `dig`

```
$ dig example.com
```

You will see something like

```
;; Query time: 38 msec
```

Now type the command again, and you should see something like:

```
;; Query time: 2 msec
```

#### ISP like real DNS Server

This would be possible using real nameserver software like bind. But if you have no experience on this you should probably start reading ahead at [bind9.net](http://www.bind9.net/) since this would be to broad to answer.

Comment: +1 dnsmasq is as easy as it comes for a local dns server, whilst bind is better known maintaining a zone file can be a pain, where as an entry in /etc/hosts is much easier, you'll want `yum install dnsmaq` for redhat derived distros

Answer (score 2):

There are only two caching recursive DNS servers that I can strongly recommend (avaiable both for Windows and UNIX variants)

1. BIND (http://www.isc.org/)
2. Unbound (http://www.unbound.net/)

The particular reason I recommend these two is DNSSEC - they both have full DNSSEC validation built-in.  You won't get that with `dnsmasq` or `tinydns`.

BIND is generally considered to be *the* reference implementation of DNS, although I'd note that because it's a full general purpose DNS server it has lots of knobs and settings that a recursive-only server doesn't need.

Unbound was designed from the ground up to be recursive only.  It's fast and lightweight.

Answer (score 1):

Bind is the most popular:
http://www.isc.org/software/bind

If you want something for windows, Windows Server has a DNS Server built in.

Not sure why you would want a local DNS server, it wont speed up DNS lookups necessarily. Keep in mind the DNS server has to run multiple queries before resolving to the IP. At a DSL or even cable, they will be slower than a DNS server at a datacenter with big pipes....

Comment: Do not use bind... Its is too much to configure and quite slow in comparison to others.. 

In fact some root servers have moved to tinydns (so i have heard)

Answer (score 0):

You kinda need a server OS to do that (as of what I know). I would install Windows Server (preferred 2003+) and install the DNS role. It has a nice little wizard that will help you set up your own DNS server.

I know that this isn't the only way, but it is a way that I am very familiar with.

-Good Luck

Comment: Why down vote? I said information that I'm familiar with, attempting to help at least a little. Add a comment if you are going to down vote.

Comment: You do not require a server OS to provide DNS services, whilst windows server does come bundled with DNS services this is not true of all operating systems, and there are a multitude of standalone software applications that could run from your windows (*eugh*) desktop

Comment: I and didn't state that I was 100% sure that you need a server OS. I just know that it is ridiculously easy in windows server 2003. I don't think that is a reason to down vote.

Comment: He did say, "as of what I know". Although the questioner stated that he knows linux, so obviously the guy is not looking for a $600+ solution.

Comment: I wouldn't down vote, it's not a wrong answer and he didn't state server OS's were the only way to do it. The questioner did say he knows linux so he's obviously is not looking for $600+ solution. But still he's new give him time to learn when to answer and when not to. I know I read this site for more than 6 months before signing up for an account.

Comment: Thanks David, I'm not really looking for a solution I just wanna learn new stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Something cool and fast is TinyDNS/DNScache

its very simple to configure and maintain..

But by far for your needs..

I would suggest dnsmasq.. it will do the job your looking for..

Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not worth it. Your server will still have to rely on an authoritative nameserver, and you probably won't have a connection to that authority that's nearly as fast as dedicated DNS servers such as what Google provides.

A couple of other things to consider: Most computers actually cache DNS entries locally for a certain period of time anyway. Furthermore, some modern browsers are now "prefetching" DNS info for links on a page - Google Chrome for example.

By the way - here is another post that provides a good answer should you still want to continue "for fun." [in house DNS server](https://serverfault.com/questions/15833/in-house-dns-server)